# Postgresql plperlu and encodings

Tags: postgresql, base64, bytea, plperlu

I want to generate a PDF in plperlu, store it in the database and then add it to an email as an attachment.

I am using PDF::Report to generate the PDF. The code looks like this:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workflow.make_pdf(report_template json, report_json json)
  RETURNS bytea AS
$BODY$

use strict;
use PDF::Report;
my $pdf = new PDF::ReportNG(PageSize => 'A4', PageOrientation => "Landscape");
...
 lots of tricky stuff to make PDF
...
return $pdf->Finish();
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

This errors with `invalid input syntax for type bytea` which I assume is something to do with the encoding of the PDF document created.

The document itself is fine as `$pdf->saveAs('/tmp/test.pdf');` creates a document that is perfectly readable.

I tried base64 encoding the result before returning it as the attachment to email will need to be in base64.

```
return MIME::base64::encode($pdf->Finish());
```

This removed the error, I can then store it in a table with:-

```
INSERT INTO weekly_report_pdfs(report) 
VALUES (make_pdf(report_template,report_json));
```

Which also works fine, and can be attached to an email, but the corruption problem persists after the base64 decode.

Exporting the file directly from the database and running `base64 -d test.b64` gives an `invalid input` error after only one line.

This appears to be something to do with the way postgres chucks bytea, as the file looks like this:-

```
MDA0OTY1MSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDQ5ODU0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwNTAxNjcgMDAwMDAgbiAK\\012dHJhaWxlcgo8PCAvUm9vdCAxIDAgUiAvU2l6ZSA0MCAvSW5mbyA0IDAgUiA+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYK\\012
```

With lots of \012 separators.

Any ideas, I've been at this for hours and am completely stumped.

Answer (score 2):

### Returning binary from plperl

When declared as returning `bytea`, a pl/perl function must actually return a postgresql text representation for `bytea`.

Consider this excerpt from [PL/Perl Functions and Arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-funcs.html) in the doc (and more specifically the last sentence):

> Anything in a function argument that is not a reference is a string,
> which is in the standard PostgreSQL external text representation for
> the relevant data type. In the case of ordinary numeric or text types,
> Perl will just do the right thing and the programmer will normally not
> have to worry about it. However, in other cases the argument will need
> to be converted into a form that is more usable in Perl. For example,
> the decode_bytea function can be used to convert an argument of type
> bytea into unescaped binary.
>
> Similarly, values passed back to PostgreSQL must be in the external
> text representation format. For example, the encode_bytea function can
> be used to escape binary data for a return value of type bytea.

According to this, you should do:

```
return encode_bytea($pdf->Finish());
```

and then the `invalid input syntax for type bytea` error would go away.

### Returning base64

If returning base64, the function should normally be declared as `RETURNS text` and the `report` column should be `text` too. That would solve the problem of having these `\012` sequences that look like a line feed (ASCII code=12 in octal) expressed  in a bytea string literal with postgres [`escape` format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html).
The line feeds are typically added by base64 encoders every 76 characters to avoid long lines in a MIME body  ([RFC-4648)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.1).

If the `report` column stays in `bytea` and the function produces base64 with `RETURNS text`, an implicit cast should happen on INSERT and it would probably be fine. Otherwise the conversion could be made explicitly with `convert_to(bytea_plperl_func(), 'US-ASCII')`
But storing `base64` in a `bytea` column doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I changed the return type to text and returned `return MIME::Base64::encode(encode('UTF-8',$test));` this solved the invalid input syntax, however there is still an encoding issue as the PDF does not display properly and I can see differences in the stream objects between the emailed version and one I create using %pdf->saveAs()

Comment: If `$test` is the PDF in binary, `encode('UTF-8',$test)` shouldn't be there. It will corrupt the PDF before converting it to base64.

Comment: The code is now `return MIME::Base64::encode($test);` from make_pdf, the reports column is a text column and I am storing the return value directly. I am adding to the email with the report value returned directly from the database. It is so nearly there but still some strange encodings.